# trying to create a file and a folder for user details

Tags: php

ok i managed to fix my issue, but the problem now , is that i cant delete the folders and files in the ftp, its supposed to be set to 777 but i simply cant get rid of the folder & the txt files, ill need that option in the future to clean up the logs once in a while..

also, is there any way to clean up the code abit?
do you see a better way to do it? thanks!

```
// create log for security messures, because user returned zero on checkup
$logusername = $_POST['username'];

$userAgent = ( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) 
&& ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] != "")) 
? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] : "Unknown";
$userIp    = ( isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) 
&& ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != ""))     
? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']     : "Unknown";
$refferer  = ( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) 
&& ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != ""))
? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']    : "Unknown";
$uri       = ( isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
&& ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != ""))
? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']     : "Unknown";
$hostname = gethostbyaddr($userIp);

//write log to file
$log_path = date("d_m_y");
$log_file = date("d_m_y");
$full_file_path = "falsehistory/$log_path/$log_file.txt";
// check if backup have user folder

if (!file_exists("$full_file_path"))
{
    $f = @fopen($full_file_path, 'w');
    // creating a new directory for the backup user
    mkdir("falsehistory/$log_path/", 0777);

    $f = @fopen($full_file_path, 'a+');
    @fputs($f, "".date("d.m.Y g:ia").": \n ".$logusername." \n ".$userIp." \n ".$hostname." \n ".$refferer." -> ".$uri." \n - \n");
    @fclose($f);
}

else
{
    $f = @fopen($full_file_path, 'a+');
    @fputs($f, "".date("d.m.Y g:ia").": \n ".$logusername." \n ".$userIp." \n ".$hostname." \n ".$refferer." -> ".$uri." \n - \n");
    @fclose($f);
}
```

Comment: You could try to use `chown()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php) to set the files to a specific owner, but other than that if your FTP user doesn't have the required access rights to delete the log files your PHP script creates, you should look for solutions on your server (by providing or achieving proper access rights) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try using `mkdir()` with the recursive parameter set to `true`:

```
mkdir($full_file_path, 0777, true);
```

It will assure that the folders on all depth levels are created.

Furthermore, there are numerous things about your code that quietly ask for improvement:

1.) You do not need to put your variable names in quotes:

For example:

```
mkdir("$full_file_path", 0777);
```

Could and should be

```
mkdir($full_file_path, 0777);
```

2.) It helps optically as well as syntactically if you separate your fixed strings from the variable components.

For example:

```
$full_file_path = "falsehistory/$log_path/$log_file.txt";
```

Could become:

```
$full_file_path = "falsehistory/" . $log_path . "/$log_file.txt";
```

3.) You are going through quite some trouble to append data to your file.

```
$f = @fopen($full_file_path, 'a+');
@fputs($f, "".date("d.m.Y g:ia").": \n ".$logusername." \n ".$userIp." \n ".$hostname." \n ".$refferer." -> ".$uri." \n - \n");
@fclose($f);
```

It can be done with way less code using `file_put_contents()` ([see the PHP manual here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php))

```
$s=date("d.m.Y g:ia") . ": \n ".$logusername." \n ".$userIp." \n ".$hostname." \n ".$refferer." -> ".$uri." \n - \n";
file_put_contents($full_file_path, $s, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: i changed the question, can you recheck it?